# Water taps open and running water when I come home

Tags: plumbing, bathtub, taps

I've had two occurances where I've come home from work to find my bath taps open and gushing water, even though they were off when I left for work. First time it was both hot and cold taps, yesterday it was just the cold water tap. My plumber is puzzled and said the washers in the taps are fine. Anyone have any ideas or had this happen to you? Two plumbers I've spoken to have no idea. And the taps were definitely off when I left the flat.

Comment: Do you have cats? I've watched one of mine knock a particularly easy-to-open tap to turn it on ... cheeky little #@$$%@

Comment: I do, but she never goes near the tub. The tap is also fairly stiff.

Comment: I've seen sink taps where, if you open it slightly and wait, it will slowly open itself until it is completely open. I haven't seen one that will do that from fully closed, though. Is this new behavior?

Comment: It happened last year. Both my hot and cold taps opened at the same time in the same tub as yesterday. I chalked it up to the renovations they were doing in the apartment next to mine. And my plumber says the water pressure in this building is really high so that might have something to do with it. But my plumber has no idea.

Comment: I have seen Washer less faucets do this with a drop in pressure. You might need to get a motion activated camera to catch the gremlins.

Comment: Basically this is not possible unless your plumbing is subjected to massive vibration.  Far more likely you forgot even though you think you didn't, or that someone's deliberately sabotaging your tub.

Comment: Not possible. I'm the only one with access to the property. I didn't use the tub that morning as the geyser had tripped the power the night before due to a faulty element. So I left it off overnight and would have had no hot water the following morning. I also get ready for work in the bathroom and would have noticed if the tap was running in the bath. Plus the water pressure is so high in the apartment the cold water tap squeals when it is open. And the fact it has happened to me twice in this apartment means it is very definitely possible as it has happened to me twice!

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue with the hot water ONLY.  Done some ‘testing’.  Mark the tap of the hot water and run some water into the bath. Close the tap and realise that it still has to go about one full turn but it feels as if it is closed. 
After about 5 minutes I open another hot water tap (the basin) and suddenly the hot water in the bath starts to run. 
When turning the hot water tap of the bath it easily turn the missing turn as mentioned above. 
I will inspect the inside of the hot water tap in the next day or two.
In the meantime I will check my marks on the tap (and wall) everytime I have used the tap.

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement! If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//diy.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//diy.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.